# Can I truncate “field_revision_body” without breaking the site?

Tags: 7, advertising

I am cleaning up a client's Drupal 7 site that has been badly hit by spam.  Both Drupal's **Backup & Migrate** module and the CLI tools such as *mysqldump* and *mysql* runs out of memory when trying to extract the single table `field_revision_body`.

My current understanding of things is that this table contains *old* versions of `field_data_body`. Provided I don't want to roll anything back, I believe I should be able truncate `field_revision_body` without breaking the site.

However, since I am unable to make a *backup* of the database in its present state, I want to check if I've understood this correctly *before* engaging in  something that cannot be reversed.

Comment: I wouldn’t truncate anything, this should ideally be scripted against the api to load and delete all but the latest revision of every node. I believe you still need the data for the current revision in the field revision table (even though it’s also in the field data table), so truncating may be too destructive anyway. BTW there’s a probable typo in your question when you reference truncating for the second time - you mention truncating the field _data_ table rather than revision

Comment: @Clive - You're right about the typo (now corrected). I'll look into the API.